# Adding projects to new PC and TFS issues

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have received a new laptop.  I have copied all of my source over from my old laptop to my new laptop.

On my new laptop, running VS2010, I did the the following to change the bindings and workspaces:

To change the workspaces:
File > Source Control > Workspaces > Select My workspace in List > changed folder paths.

To bind my source:
File > Source Control > Change Source Control > Change Source Control.

Now the problem is when I try to check out my solution for edit, I get the following error:

The item could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it.

I see some of the files are missing, but why would this be?

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to create a new workspace on your new laptop.